# Map enter key to submit while not inside input

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, submit, enter

I have a form with multiple input boxes that I'm trying to get to submit when I press the enter key, regardless of whether or not one of the inputs is currently highlighted. That is, I want to be able to enter text, click the background of the page, hit enter, and have the form submitted. I have tried making a hidden button, but this solution only appears to submit when the cursor is inside one of the inputs.

Answer (score 4):

Use `onkeypress` on `document` using pure javascript:

[Fiddle.(demo)](http://jsfiddle.net/WC4wR/)

**JS:**

```
var form = document.getElementById('form');
document.onkeypress = function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode === 13) //if enter pressed
    {
        form.submit();
    }

}
```

Here's another solution using `addEventListener`, *as suggested by Matt*:

```
var form = document.getElementById('form');
function submitForm(e) {
    if(e.keyCode === 13) //if enter pressed
    {
        form.submit();
    }

}

document.addEventListener('keypress', function() {submitForm(event)}, false);
```

***As a side note:**
I would discourage you using **jQuery** on places where **pure JS** can help you easily that's why gave you a javascript solution. I would discourage that because **jQuery** increases the load on the server alot!*

*As you said you are new to javascript do the following steps to get your script running everytime:*

1. Add my code to a file with `.js` extension
2. Add `<script src="your_filename.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` before your closing `</body>` tag.
3. Refresh your page and voila.

Comment: Good job on the Pure JavaScript answer. It might help some people to get to use the language instead of a bunch of libraries adding 15 Petabytes to your website.

Comment: Upvote for no jQuery, but you should use `addEventListener` instead of setting the `onkeypress` attribute.

Comment: Thanks @MattBryant, but why I should use `eventListener` when I just want the function to be executed only one on the `document`?

Comment: Among other reasons, setting the `onkeypress` attribute will overwrite anything that is already there, whereas you can have multiple `eventlistener`s attached to one element.  For his case, it probably doesn't matter.  In general however, it's the better method.

Comment: Forgive my lack of knowledge on the matter, I'm fairly new to this, but how would I run this javascript from an html file? I assume I would use <script> and </script> around it, but how do I make it get called all the time instead of when a button object is pushed (this is the only way I think I've seen javascript called, using onClick).

Comment: @user2568916 put this javascript into a seprate file called "your_filename.js" then add this before the closing `</body>` tag: `<script src="your_filename.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` that's it! You're done.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I am not able to get it working still though. I can get it to call an alert placed inside the if-statement but when I set the value of var form it is set to null, and thus the call to form.submit() fails. I realize that this is an unrelated problem to my initial question, but I was wondering if you could possibly explain why this might be happening. Thanks!

Comment: @user2568916 in my example I set the `id` attribute of the form to `form` in your case it might be something else and though replace the function `getElementById`'s argument or parameter by your form's `id` attribute and I am sure it will work then.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of jQuery:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {

    if (e.keyCode == 13) {

         $('#your-form').submit();

         return false;
    }

});
```

Comment: I'm sorry, we were posting it at the same time I guess!

Comment: Answer is purely valid. And we all copied our knowledge from someone else's anyways. Questions like this usualy get 15 answers in 6 seconds, being all the same thing, but this is the jQuery alternative :)

Comment: you answered `(54-3) = 51 seconds` after me!

Comment: I was checking my answer, so that took me 51 seconds more than yours. Take it easy, every user understands that copying is useless ;-)